# Vestacp just use apache

Tags: webserver, vesta

i recently install vestacp but I don't want to use ngix I would like to use just Apache

Do I have to re install all?

How can I remove ngix from my vestacp?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can remove nginx without reinstall.

1. Stop nginx

   service nginx stop
2. Remove package

// In Debian/Ubuntu

```
apt-get remove nginx
```

// In CentOS

```
yum remove nginx
```

3. Change vesta configuration

   cd /usr/local/vesta/conf

   sed -i "/PROXY_*/d" vesta.conf

   sed -i "s/8080/80/" vesta.conf

   sed -i "s/8443/443/" vesta.conf
4. Change httpd configuration

// In Debian/Ubuntu

```
cd /etc/apache2/conf.d
```

// In CentOS

```
cd /etc/httpd/conf.d
```

And next do that:

```
sed -i "s/8080/80/" *.conf

sed -i "s/8443/443/" *.conf
```

5. Rebuild vhost configs

   for user in $(v-list-sys-users plain); do v-rebuild-web-domains $user; done

You can found that instructions in:
http://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-remove-nginx-rhel-centos

http://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-remove-nginx-debian-ubuntu